# Using functions as map keys in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I want to use functions as keys in a Map like this:

```
var timers : Map<Void->Void, snow.api.Timer>;
```

But Haxe won't compile:

> Abstract Map has no @:to function that accepts IMap<Void -> Void, snow.api.Timer>

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to write a custom implementation:

```
import haxe.Constraints;

class FunctionMap<K:Function,V> implements IMap<K,V> {
  private var _keys : Array<K>;
  private var _values : Array<V>;

  public function new () {
    _keys = [];
    _values = [];
  }

  public function get(k:K):Null<V> {
    var keyIndex = index(k);
    if (keyIndex < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return _values[keyIndex];
    }
  }

  public function set(k:K, v:V):Void {
    var keyIndex = index(k);
    if (keyIndex < 0) {
        _keys.push(k);
        _values.push(v);
    } else {
        _values[keyIndex] = v;
    }
  }

  public function exists(k:K):Bool {
    return index(k) >= 0;
  }

  public function remove(k:K):Bool {
    var keyIndex = index(k);
    if (keyIndex < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        _keys.splice(keyIndex, 1);
        _values.splice(keyIndex, 1);
        return true;
    }
  }

  public function keys():Iterator<K> {
    return _keys.iterator();
  }

  public function iterator():Iterator<V> {
    return _values
        .iterator();
  }

  public function toString():String {
    var s = new StringBuf();
    s.add("{");
    for( i in 0..._keys.length ) {
        s.add('<function>');
        s.add(" => ");
        s.add(Std.string(_values[i]));
        if( i < _keys.length - 1 )
            s.add(", ");
    }
    s.add("}");
    return s.toString();
  }   


  private function index(key:K) : Int {
    for (i in 0..._keys.length) {
        if (Reflect.compareMethods(key, _keys[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
  }}
```

http://try.haxe.org/#DdF31

Comment: Yeah , it was my second intention to use two array and sync them with one for key and second for value .
So no build in way to do this?

Thanks for you code, and implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in try.haxe.org, and the compiler doesn't seem to like it, so I'm guessing the answer is "no."

You could get around this with some [cleverness](http://try.haxe.org/#c574b):

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var map:Map<VoidVoid,String>;
        map = new Map<VoidVoid,String>();
        var thing = {func:foo};
        map.set(thing,"bar");
        trace(map.get({func:foo}));  //fails
        trace(map.get(thing));       //succeeds;
    }

    static function foo():Void
    {

    }
}

typedef VoidVoid = {
    var func:Void->Void;
}
```

But that's not an ideal solution because wrapping it in a typedef like that will make it fail if it's not the exact same instance, even if the value inside is the same.

I also tried making a `Map<Dynamic,String>` since you can stuff function references in those, but that didn't work either.

At this point I should ask, what problem are you trying to solve this way? Perhaps it could be better solved some other way.

Comment: Thanks for you inspect,

In Unity3D, you can work with Coroutine. To call a Coroutine you can call StartCoroutine(myFnct()) and to stop it you can call StopCoroutine(myFnct()).

I want to reproduce the same behaviour in haxe. 

I have a manager that can add/remove function. I find the map<Void->Void, ...> is good solution to assign some behaviour on some function. And I like the structure to avoid collision rather than use a map with the name of the function to identify it.

Perhaps it exist better solution to do this. 
Thanks for your help